# Error al subir una imagen (con código)

Tags: base-de-datos, nodejs, angular, mongodb, imagen

Al seleccionar la imagen y darle a enviar, tendría que subir los datos a la base de datos, obtener el id del objeto y con el id se tendría que actualizar añadiendo la imagen pero me da dos errores:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined at uploadImage
(C:\users\javis\onedrive\escritorio\master-java\backend\controllers\project.js:95:44)
```

Aquí está la parte del backend donde me da el error

```js
uploadImage:function(req,res){
  let projectID=req.params.id; 
  var fileName='Imagen no subida...';
  if(req.files){
    var filePath = req.files.image.path;  //AQUI ME MARCA EL ERROR
    var fileSplit=filePath.split('\\');
    var fileName=fileSplit[1];
    var extSplit=fileName.split('\.');
    var fileExt=extSplit[1];
    if(fileExt=='png'|fileExt=='jpg'|fileExt=='jpeg'|fileExt=='gif'){
      Project.findByIdAndUpdate(projectID,{image:fileName},{new:true}, (err,projectUpdated)=>{
        if(err) return res.status(500).send({message:'La imagen no se ha subido'});
        if(!projectUpdated) return res.status(404).send({message:'El proyecto no existe y no se le ha asignado la imagen'});
        return res.status(200).send({project:projectUpdated});
      });
    } else {
      fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => {
        return res.status(200).send({message:'La extensión no es válida'});
      });
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(200).send({message: fileName})
  }
}
```

Aquí debajo os dejo el servicio a través del cual subo la imagen:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { global } from './global';

@Injectable()

export class uploadService{
  public url:string;
  constructor(){
    this.url=global.url;
  }
  makeFileRequest(url:string, params:Array<string>, files:Array<File>, name:string) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      var formData:any=new FormData();
      var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest;
      for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
        formData.append(name, files[i].name);
      }
      xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xhr.readyState==4){
          if(xhr.status==200){
            resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
          } else {
            reject(xhr.response);
          }
        }
      }
      xhr.open('POST',url,true);
      xhr.send(formData);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola Javitheck. Puedes adjuntar el servicio con el que envías la subida de archivos por angular, y por la parte de node tienes en el backend fileupload(), importado antes de su uso?

Comment: Hola, he subido ya el servicio y he marcado donde me dice la terminal que está el error en el primer código. Lo que tengo importado es el servicio en el typescript de ese componente, no se si te refieres a eso

Comment: No se si te solucionará el problema, pero lo que puedo ver, es que envías mas de un archivo, pero no me queda claro,  `formData.append(name, files[i].name);` por este código, entonces estaría bien saber, con un console.log(formData), que contenido tiene, por que parece que solo envía el último archivo ,me imagino que el fileupload y el cors lo tienes cubierto.

Answer (score 0):

No se si te solucionará el problema, pero lo que puedo ver, es que envías mas de un archivo, pero no me queda claro,  `formData.append(name, files[i].name);` por este código, entonces estaría bien saber, con un console.log(formData), que contenido tiene, por que parece que solo envía el último archivo, yo creo que por aquí podría estar el problema ,me imagino que el fileupload y el cors lo tienes cubierto. Una vez comprobado lo anterior, podrías hacer un `return res.status(200).json({'files':  req.files})`, y ver que responde.
Otra manera sería hacer una petición http, con angular y añadir los headers y enviarlo, hay que importar las librerías correspondientes en el módulo y el servicio

ejemplo

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data');
this.http.post(this.url, formData,{ headers});
```

Espero que te sirva.